# What is Madhvācārya's translation and commentary to ŚB 12.13.16?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, reference-request, resource, madhvacharya

I wanted to know about Śrī Madhvācārya's interpretation of ŚB 12.13.16, but I cannot find a PDF of it.